# how to get the values using regex in python3

Tags: python-3.x, regex

string = 
`# Combinations selected:Mod Size 1024 with SHA-1(Salt len: 20); SHA-224(Salt len: 20); SHA-256(Salt len: 20); SHA-384(Salt len: 20); SHA-512(Salt len: 20);; Mod Size 2048 with SHA-1(Salt len: 20); SHA-224(Salt len: 28); SHA-256(Salt len: 32); SHA-384(Salt len: 48); SHA-512(Salt len: 64);; Mod Size 3072 with SHA-1(Salt len: 0); SHA-224(Salt len: 0); SHA-256(Salt len: 0); SHA-384(Salt len: 24); SHA-512(Salt len: 0);`

I've tried so many regex
but I did not get any answer

output:

```
{'Mod Size 1024':'SHA-1(Salt len: 20); SHA-224(Salt len: 20); SHA-256(Salt len: 20); SHA-384(Salt len: 20); SHA-512(Salt len: 20)',  
'Mod Size 2048' :'SHA-1(Salt len: 20); SHA-224(Salt len: 28); SHA-256(Salt len: 32); SHA-384(Salt len: 48); SHA-512(Salt len: 64)'}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `re.findall` with pattern `r"(Mod Size \d+) with (.*?);(;|$)"`

```
import re

string = "# Combinations selected:Mod Size 1024 with SHA-1(Salt len: 20); SHA-224(Salt len: 20); SHA-256(Salt len: 20); SHA-384(Salt len: 20); SHA-512(Salt len: 20);; Mod Size 2048 with SHA-1(Salt len: 20); SHA-224(Salt len: 28); SHA-256(Salt len: 32); SHA-384(Salt len: 48); SHA-512(Salt len: 64);; Mod Size 3072 with SHA-1(Salt len: 0); SHA-224(Salt len: 0); SHA-256(Salt len: 0); SHA-384(Salt len: 24); SHA-512(Salt len: 0);"

for i in re.findall(r"(Mod Size \d+) with (.*?);(;|$)", string):
    print(i[:-1])
```

**Output:**

```
('Mod Size 1024', 'SHA-1(Salt len: 20); SHA-224(Salt len: 20); SHA-256(Salt len: 20); SHA-384(Salt len: 20); SHA-512(Salt len: 20)')
('Mod Size 2048', 'SHA-1(Salt len: 20); SHA-224(Salt len: 28); SHA-256(Salt len: 32); SHA-384(Salt len: 48); SHA-512(Salt len: 64)')
('Mod Size 3072', 'SHA-1(Salt len: 0); SHA-224(Salt len: 0); SHA-256(Salt len: 0); SHA-384(Salt len: 24); SHA-512(Salt len: 0)')
```

Comment: can you provide a bit of explanation to the regex.